# Android CheckBox - Removing a previously setOnCheckedChangeListener

Tags: android, checkbox, android-cursoradapter

I have an application that displays a ListView using a CursorAdapter that I have customized. Within my custom CursorAdapter.bindView, I have a CheckBox object that I set the checked value (based on a column on the cursor) and set a clickListener. Here is my code:

```
    CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_done);
    mCheckBox.setChecked(isDone);
    mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
                AW.getDB().updateTask(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_ID)), isChecked);
                TD.displayTasks();
        }
    });
```

The only problem is that when Android recycles my views, the onCheckedChangeListener is still active, and thus the call to setChecked() causes that code within the listener to run. I would like to know how to invalidata the onCheckedChangedListener right before the code I have included runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
// c is the Cursor you are getting
CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.list_done);
mCheckBox.setTag(new Integer(c.getPosition());
mCheckBox.setChecked(isDone);
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        Integer posInt = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();

        int pos = posInt.intValue();
        c.moveToPosition(pos);
            AW.getDB().updateTask(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_ID)), isChecked);
            TD.displayTasks();
    }
});
```

There are lots of optimizations you can do to above code. I just illustrated the basic logic.

Comment: Best answer and +1 for inadvertently answering my other question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549386/mcheckbox-setoncheckedchangelistener-within-cursoradapter

Answer (score 13):

You can call `mcheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);` if it is done inside the `onCheckedChangeListener`, you need to declare `mCheckBox` **`final`**.