# Switch Widget - onCheckedChanged triggers when setting values in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a listview with a Switch widget per listview item, the problem I am having is when I set the value in my ArrayAdapter the setOnCheckedChangeListener get triggered.  How can I set the value in my adapter without triggering the setOnCheckedChangeListener?  I have found another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549214/android-checkbox-removing-a-previously-setoncheckedchangelistener/8549298#8549298) but this does not work for me. Below is my ArrayAdapter code.

```
public class AlarmsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Alarms> {

private List<Alarms> alarmsList;
private Context context;

private ContactDetailsFragment cdFragment;

public AlarmsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Alarms> alarms) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context=context;
    alarmsList=alarms;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Alarms alarm = alarmsList.get(position);

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if( view == null ) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.alarm_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.alarmLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarmLabel);
        holder.alarmDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarmDate);
        holder.alarmTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.alarmTime);
        holder.alarmEnabled = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.alarmEnabled);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if(alarm != null) {
        int alarmId = alarm.getAlarmDay();
        holder.alarmLabel.setText( String.valueOf(alarmId));

        // Alarm Date Time
        long mDateTime = alarm.getAlarmTime();
        Date nDate = new Date(mDateTime);

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");

        holder.alarmDate.setText( dateFormat.format(nDate) );
        holder.alarmTime.setText( timeFormat.format(nDate));
        holder.alarmEnabled.setChecked((alarm.getIsOn() == 1) ? true : false);
        holder.alarmEnabled.setTag(alarm.get_uid());

        holder.alarmEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                alarm.setIsOn( (isChecked) ? 1:0 );
                cdFragment.addCanceledAlarm(alarm);
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView alarmLabel;
    TextView alarmDate;
    TextView alarmTime;
    Switch alarmEnabled;
}

public void setCdFragment(ContactDetailsFragment cdFragment) {
    this.cdFragment = cdFragment;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways how you could deal with such situation.

First and easiest way is to remove `OnCheckedChangeListener` each time before you call `setChecked` from your code.

```
holder.alarmTime.setText(timeFormat.format(nDate));

// Here we remove the listener, so it won't be triggered
holder.alarmEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

holder.alarmEnabled.setChecked(alarm.getIsOn() == 1);
holder.alarmEnabled.setTag(alarm.get_uid());
holder.alarmEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...
```

Second way is to add some code to your `OnCheckedChangeListener` where your verify if new state is different from current state of a switch. Code example:

```
holder.alarmEnabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (alarm.getIsOn() != (isChecked ? 1 : 0)) {
            // This code is executed only if new state
            // of a switch is different from current state
            alarm.setIsOn( (isChecked) ? 1 : 0);
            cdFragment.addCanceledAlarm(alarm);
        }
    }
});
```

Third way is to introduce some kind of a flag, which indicates whether switch state was changed by user or from code. So in your listener you could ignore cases when you call `setChecked` explicitly from code.

Comment: Thanks @vasart, I used the first option, it solved my problem.